# Subdocuments in MongoDB and Yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2

How should I declare the `attributes` public function of a class (model) that extends from `ActiveRecord` if I'm willing to use subdocuments?

Take for example this simple MongoDB structure:

```
_id: 'a34tfsert89w734y0tas9dgtuwn034t3',
name: 'Bob',
surnames: {
    'first': 'Foo',
    'second': 'Bar'
},
age: 27,
preferences: {
    lang: 'en',
    currency: 'EUR'
}
```

How should my `attributes` function look like?

```
public function attributes() {
    return [
        '_id',
        'name',
        'surnames',
        'surnames.first', <--- like this?
        .....
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDb Extension for Yii 2 **[does not provide any special way to work with embedded documents (sub-documents)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html#working-with-embedded-documents)**. To do that you will need to first deal with custom validations. You could try the following approach: The general pattern is to first build a **[custom validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/632/mongodb-s-embedded-documents-mapping-for-activerecord-in-yii2/#hh2)**, say \common\validators\EmbedDocValidator.php

```
namespace common\validators;

use yii\validators\Validator;

class EmbedDocValidator extends Validator
{
    public $scenario;
    public $model;

    /**
     * Validates a single attribute.
     * Child classes must implement this method to provide the actual validation logic.
     *
     * @param \yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord $object the data object to be validated
     * @param string $attribute the name of the attribute to be validated.
     */
    public function validateAttribute($object, $attribute)
    {
        $attr = $object->{$attribute};
        if (is_array($attr)) {
            $model = new $this->model;
            if($this->scenario){
                $model->scenario = $this->scenario;
            }
            $model->attributes = $attr;
            if (!$model->validate()) {
                foreach ($model->getErrors() as $errorAttr) {
                    foreach ($errorAttr as $value) {
                        $this->addError($object, $attribute, $value);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->addError($object, $attribute, 'should be an array');
        }
    }

}
```

and model for the embedded document \common\models\Preferences.php

```
namespace common\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class Preferences extends Model
{

    /**
     * @var string $lang
     */
    public $lang;

        /**
     * @var string $currency
     */
    public $currency;


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['lang', 'currency'], 'required'],           
        ];
    }

}
```

And **[setup the validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/632/mongodb-s-embedded-documents-mapping-for-activerecord-in-yii2/#hh4)** in the top-level model 
In common\models\User.php:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['preferences', 'name'], 'required'],
        ['preferences', 'common\validators\EmbedDocValidator', 'scenario' => 'user','model'=>'\common\models\Preferences'],
        ];
    }
```

The **[general recommendation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html#working-with-embedded-documents)** is **[avoiding use of embedded documents](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2492)** moving their attributes at the top level of the document. For example: instead of

```
{
    name: 'Bob',
    surnames: {
        'first': 'Foo',
        'second': 'Bar'
    },
    age: 27,
    preferences: {
        lang: 'en',
        currency: 'EUR'
    }
}
```

use following structure:

```
{
    name: 'Bob',
    surnames_first: 'Foo',
    surnames_second: 'Bar'
    age: 27,
    preferences_lang: 'en',
    preferences_currency: 'EUR'    
}
```

which you can then declare as an **`ActiveRecord`** class by extending yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord and implement the `collectionName` and `'attributes'` methods:

```
use yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the name of the index associated with this ActiveRecord class.
     */
    public static function collectionName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @return array list of attribute names.
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return ['_id', 'name', 'surnames_first', 'surnames_second', 'age', 'preferences_lang', 'preferences_currency'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying here. Since your answer I contacted with Yii devs on this issue, let's see where this drives us to: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4899